# Option to show android app installation from my web page while signing in with Google+

Tags: oauth-2.0, google-api, google-play-services, google-oauth, google-play

I have just seen in a webpage(livsports.in) where once I SignIn to the page via Google+, first they show up a screen to authenticate and Grant access(This is normal OAuth2 flow). But then after granting access, they show a screen wherein it asks to install LIV Sports on my android device. **This screen doesn't show up if I didn't configure my android device in Google Play Store**. I would like to implement this in my webpage.

Can someone please help me on how this can be achieved? Is there some trick involved or is there something in OAuth2 that I'm missing? Please help

> **Would you also like to install LIV Sports on your Android device?**

[image: Screenshot]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Refer to https://developers.google.com/+/web/signin/android-app-installs

By adding the Google+ Sign-In button to your web site, you can automatically prompt your users to download your Android app over the air to their Android devices. To enable this feature, you must use the same Google Developers Console project for your Web and Android clients, and configure your web app's sign-in button.